# Does generalization of axioms apply also to theorems?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

In Enderton's book "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" (second edition), he includes six axiom groups, and allows also for a generalization of those axioms such that if $\Psi$ is an axiom then $\forall x \Psi$ is also an axiom.

Is this rule also intended to apply to theorems from those axioms?  In other words, if $\Psi$ is a theorem of $\Gamma$, can I conclude $\forall x\Psi$ is also a theorem?

Comment: YES; see Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd ed Harcourt - 2001), page 117 : **Generalization Theorem** If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ does not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$. But you cannot invoke "directly" the "generalization" principle of page 112: it applies only to *logical* axioms. For a math theory, like *group theory*, we apply the **Gen Th** with as $\Gamma$ the set of (closed) *group axioms*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the first edition of Enderton's book, but I conjecture that what I'm about to write is also true for the second edition.  The axioms are defined to be formulas of certain particular forms along with anything obtainable as generalizations of them (i.e., attaching universal quantifiers that govern the whole formula).  There is no rule of inference that allows you to generalize theorems in the same way.  There is, however, a metatheorem, called the Generalization Theorem, which implies, as a special case, that if a formula $\phi$ is provable from just the axioms, then so are its generalizations.

Notice, though, that the deduction of $\forall x\,\phi$ would not be just the deduction of $\phi$ followed by a single step that attaches the universal quantifier.  Rather, the whole deduction of $\phi$ needs to be modified --- with universal quantifiers attached to formulas and additional lines inserted into the proof --- to produce a deduction of $\forall x\,\phi$.

Also, if you're dealing with deductions that use some hypotheses in addition to the logical axioms, then the Generalization Theorem applies only when the variable in the quantifier you want to attach is not free in any of those additional hypotheses.

Answer (score 2):

If the logic in question is halfway sane (such as if its entailment relation agrees with ordinary first-order logic) then yes -- except, possibly, if $\Gamma$ contains $x$ free. You don't always get to infer $\forall x.p(x)$from $p(y)$.

Proving that this is the case depends on details of the proof system that you have not given, though. In some systems it is a *primitive rule* that $\psi$ entails $\forall x.\psi$.

Comment: One should note though that *semantically*, $\forall x \psi$ really is the same as $\psi$ if $x$ isn't free in $\psi$ - $\forall x \psi$ is then a statement like "For all $n$, 1 + 1 = 2".

Comment: Thanks, Henning.  To be clear, Enderton has effectively two sets of rules for generalization: First -- and this seems apply to all axioms -- is simply that if $\Psi$ is an axiom then $\forall x \Psi$ is also an axiom.  He also adds the axiom group 4, which states that any statement of this form is an axiom whenever x is not free in alpha: $\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha$.  Based on this, I could also conclude that $\forall y (\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha)$ is an axiom, provided that x is not free an alpha (y might be free in alpha).

Comment: @BillProvince: Do you also have generalized versions of MP (from $\forall x.\varphi$ and $\forall x.\varphi\to\psi$ conclude $\forall x.\psi$)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  Enderton differentiates between axioms and inference rules, and MP is clearly an inference rule.

Comment: @BillProvince: That doesn't really answer whether the version of MP you have works under universal quantifiers or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: So the short answer to the question is 'no', or at least not in a single step.  However, you can get it in a couple steps.  One axiom schema is $(\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)) \rightarrow ((\forall x \alpha) \rightarrow (\forall x \beta))$  So, if you are given the propositions you state then from this axiom, you can draw the conclusion.

Comment: @Bill: Okay, that wasn't one of the axioms you described in the first comment above. That ought to be enough to make the theorem Andreas describes work.