# In meta-math does the sequence matter for $\bf ∀x$?

Tags: logic, meta-math

For example, if I have an axiom starting with $\bf ∀x∀x'\dots$ , would it still be an axiom if the only difference is that the sequence has changed to $\bf∀x'∀x\dots$?

Comment: You can't swap $\exists$ and $\forall$, but you can swap the order $\forall$ with other $\forall$, and $\exists$ with other $\exists$.

Comment: Does this also apply to axioms?

Comment: It's not technically an axiom of you switch them, but it is quickly proven from the axiom without any appear to any other axioms other than the rules of first order logic.

Comment: So would it ruin a formal proof, if it starts with quantifiers that have switched places compared to a logically equivalent axiom?

Comment: It the step asserted it was an axiom in a 100% formal proof, then yes.

Comment: Would you consider $3+4=7$ an axiom?  Why or why not?

Comment: @DanielV Huh? It can be an axiom -- of any theory silly enough to add it as one. Whether something is an axiom or not isn't a matter of opinion. Anyway the example is irrelevant to the question and to the comment thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If adjacent quantifiers of the same kind (both existential or both universal) are swapped, the result is a logically equivalent statement.

Beyond this little can be said. You may find discussions of pre-nex normal form helpful.

In most cases we *do not say* formally that one statement is an axiom just because it is a logical equivalent of a statement that is an axiom.  It is possible however that in *one particular circumstance* the swapping of two universal quantifiers, just as outlined in the Question, would meet the criterion of being an axiom precisely when the version before swapping quantifiers is an axiom.

That is the case of the [Scheme of Generalization of Axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750130/does-generalization-of-axioms-apply-also-to-theorems), often abbreviated *AxGen*, a provision of many formalizations of predicate calculus:

> If $\varphi$ is an axiom of the predicate calculus, then $\forall x \; \varphi$ is an axiom also.

This axiom scheme (as it is not a single axiom, but a rule that allows us to generate many axioms from other axioms) will let us introduce zero or many universal quantifiers onto another axiom of the predicate calculus.

In this specific case (when $\varphi$ is an axiom of the predicate calculus) it is true that $\forall x \forall x'\; \varphi$ and $\forall x' \forall x \; \varphi$ are equally to be considered axioms, and with equal justifications.

Comment: Thanks! Although both are logically the same, would both also count as axioms?

Comment: That's a bit tricky and I will add something to my answer.